# Converting JSON string to Java object does not populate values in inner Arraylist

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am trying to convert the JSON string into java object using GSON.

My JSON format is:

```
form = {
              appName:'',
              specialChars:'',
              resKeyword:'',
              inputType:'',
              noOfFiles:'',
              validationDetails: [
                  {  feedFileName:'', 
                     dataTypes:'',           
                     validationRules:[
                         {  headerName:'',
                           mappingAtribute:'',
                           isMandatory:'',
                           isUnique:'',
                           dataType:''                                      }]                       
                  }]
        };
```

I have created 3 bean classes: FormData, ValidationDetails and Validation Rules

FormData.java:

```
  public class FormData {
    private String appName;
    private String specialChars;
    private String resKeyword;
    private String inputType;
    private String noOfFiles;
    ArrayList<ValidationDetails> validationDetails= new ArrayList<ValidationDetails>();
//.... getters and setters
}
```

ValidationDetails.java:

```
 public class ValidationDetails {
    private String feedFileName; 
    private String dataTypes;
    ArrayList<ValidationRules> validationRule= new ArrayList<ValidationRules>();
//.... getters and setters
}
```

ValidationRules.java:

```
 public class ValidationRules { 
    private String headerName;  
    private String mappingAtribute;
    private String isUnique;
    private String isMandatory;
    private String  dataType;
//.... getters and setters
}
```

Now when I am trying to convert the json string using below code:

```
 Gson g = new Gson();
 FormData form = g.fromJson(json, FormData.class);
ArrayList<ValidationDetails> validationDetailsArrayList = form.getValidationDetails();
// iterating over ArrayList
for(ValidationDetails a: validationDetailsArrayList){
   ArrayList<ValidationRules> validationRulesArrayList = a.getValidationRule();
//
System.out.println(a.getValidationRule()); // here this ArrayList is getting null
}
```

So the ArrayList **validationRulesArrayList** does not populated with the values from the JSON string. I have spent a lot of time in this. 
Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you try with 'List' instead of ArrayList

Comment: It got resolved.
Actually, I made a mistake.
In my json format the inner array is **"validationRules"** but in the POJO, I defined **validationRule**. which is why it was not mapped properly earlier. 

Anyways, Thanks a lot @utkusonmez.